# Why is my ID changing with internet connectivity?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, uniqueidentifier

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer) to generate a unique hardware ID for system. The problem is that the ID generated is different when internet is connected, and different when internet is disconnected.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    private static string fingerPrint = string.Empty;
    public static string GetUniqueID()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fingerPrint))
        {
            fingerPrint = GetHash("CPU " + cpuId() + "\nBIOS " + 
                biosId() + "\nBASE " + baseId()
                + "\nVIDEO " + videoId() +"\nMAC "+ macId()
            );
        }
        return fingerPrint;
    }
    private static string GetHash(string s)
    {
        MD5 sec = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bt = enc.GetBytes(s);
        return GetHexString(sec.ComputeHash(bt));
    }
    private static string GetHexString(byte[] bt)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++)
        {
            byte b = bt[i];
            int n, n1, n2;
            n = (int)b;
            n1 = n & 15;
            n2 = (n >> 4) & 15;
            if (n2 > 9)
                s += ((char)(n2 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
            else
                s += n2.ToString();
            if (n1 > 9)
                s += ((char)(n1 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
            else
                s += n1.ToString();
            if ((i + 1) != bt.Length && (i + 1) % 2 == 0) s += "-";
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static string identifier
    (string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue)
    {
        string result = "";
        System.Management.ManagementClass mc = 
    new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (mo[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString() == "True")
            {
                //Only get the first one
                if (result == "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
    {
        string result = "";
        System.Management.ManagementClass mc = 
    new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (result == "")
            {
                try
                {
                    result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static string cpuId()
    {
        string retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "UniqueId");
        if (retVal == "")
        {
            retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
            if (retVal == "")
            {
                retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Name");
                if (retVal == "") 
                {
                    retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
                }
                retVal += identifier("Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed");
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private static string biosId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "IdentificationCode")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
    }

    private static string diskId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model")
        + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature")
        + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
    }

    private static string baseId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Model")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
    }

    private static string videoId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_VideoController", "DriverVersion")
        + identifier("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
    }

    private static string macId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration", 
            "MACAddress", "IPEnabled");
    }
```

`GetUniqueID()` is the function which hashes the various IDs. Why is the ID generated different with and without internet?

Comment: How about removing the tons of code and only showing the thing that is really needed to understand your question?

Comment: @UweKeim did you check the code ? most of the code is being used

Comment: A bit of debugging should make you able to detect the differences itself... the generated ids for example, are they the same when connected or disconnected? What did you try to find out yourself already?

Comment: @PeterBons solved the problem by removing mac from the hash...why would mac id be different with / without internet connection ?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I think its because when you are disconnected, your network interface is disabled and as such, it is unable to retrieve MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this 1000s of lines of complex logic, can't you simple use MAC id of the device.   It will remain same all the time or Device Serial Key that is Bios serial of the device. Bios key will be available  even if there's no network.

Comment: does mac id change with/without network ?? because removing mac id from the hash solved my problem

Comment: @mrid IMO, you should _really_ [learn how to use a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp).

Comment: @UweKeim noted :)

Answer (score 1):

My team once tried to build a similar piece of code to generate a unique id based off of machine settings without using persistent storage.  E.g `Hash(hostname, username, domain name, mac address, etc...)`.  Seemed like a good idea at the time, but turns out to be inherently unreliable as some of the APIs that should be consistent at returning these values, aren't always so.

The simpler and more reliable approach is to generate a GUID and persist it to the registry (or file on disk, or even the Windows Credential Store).

```
    static string GetUniqueID()
    {
        string result;
        string registry_path = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MyApp";  // substitue your own app name here
        Object obj = Registry.GetValue(registry_path, "UniqueID", null);
        if ((obj == null) || !(obj is string))
        {
            result = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Registry.SetValue(registry_path, "UniqueID", result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = (string)obj;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It's also faster than making WMI calls too.

Comment: This way, I can use someone else's license on my system if I know where the program is saving the system ID.

Comment: The OP never said anything about storing a license key. But even if the key could be inferred from environment alone, a *determined hacker* could still find ways to intercept the key with a debugger. The degree that you go to protect a secret value should be decided by what level of determination of hacking you are trying to thwart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’ve picked a wrong tutorial.

MAC changes when you connect/disconnect due to the 2 reasons. First, most PCs have more than 1 network card, and the order in which they appear in WMI is undefined. Second, by default, Windows 10 sometimes [randomizes WiFi MAC address](https://it.nmu.edu/docs/disable-random-hardware-address-windows-10) each time you connect to a WiFi network

The rest of the IDs you’re using are not much better.

videoId is unstable because driver version will update when you update the driver, BTW some windows updates include new versions of GPU drivers

diskId is unstable because users plug USB flash drives or external  hard drives.

cpuId is unreliable because it only include information specific to CPU model, i.e. for a mainstream CPU you’ll have many millions of people in the world with the same cpuId.